# ActiveRecord: why self. instead of @ to access column values in a Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm confused why column values for a record cannot be accessed using @column_name. Why are they not instance variables? How is activerecord holding their value? Why is it necessary to prefix the column name with 'self.' for assignment?

Thank you for clarifying this mystery for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because if you mistype @f00 its a pain to figure out why your code isn't working when you meant @foo or @Foo. This way there will be a "no method error" on a typo instead of making a new variable you didn't want

## Edit

I misread the question. I thought you meant about inside the ActiveRecord source when they do that. The real reason is because ActiveRecord is implemented almost entirely through reflection. It checks the database for column_names and then dynamically makes setters and getters for those fields via method_missing. If I recall correctly after you use the self.field it sets @field. This might be hidden somewhere like in @attributes[:field].